# Value not posted when click on submit in php

Tags: php, html

Simple php code to post a value  and echo it inside if(isset()), when click on submit button, but it's not working.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['q']))
    {
        $q=$_GET['q'];
        //echo "thisss iss qqqq".$q; this is working
        $_SESSION['q']=$q;

        if($q=="1")
        {
        ?>
            <form action='#'>
                <tr>
                    <input type='text' name='txt_code' >
                    <input type='submit' name='code_sub' value='Showcd'>
                </tr>
            </form>
        <?php
        }
```

//here I wrote code for to echo $bkCode when click on 'showcd' button but it's not working

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["code_sub"]))
    {
        echo $bkCode=$_POST['txt_code']; // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    } 

}
?>
```

It doesn't even enter inside the `if (isset($_POST["code_sub"]))` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default action of a form is `GET`. You have to specify that u want to do a POST :

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
```

Comment: No problem at all c-:

Answer (score 0):

A first, you should set the var, and after that a simple output:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["code_sub"]))
{
    $bkCode=$_POST['txt_code']; // THIS IS WORKING
    echo $bkCode;
}

?>
```

Also you need to set the form method to "POST"!

```
<form action='the_link' method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

For using the post method

```
<form action='the_link' method="POST">
```

This will help ..:)